# Треугольник линиями

Tags: delphi

Как рисуется треугольник в delphi линиями?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала вам нужно раздобыть экземпляр TCanvas (у компонента, окна, битмапа). А потом просто:

```
var canvas : TCanvas;
...
begin
  Canvas := .... //Где-то взяли
  with Canvas do begin 
    MoveTo(x1, y1);
    LineTo(x2, y2);
    LineTo(x3, y3);
    LineTo(x1, y1);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: а как мне его покрасивше сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Вот, как пример, процедура рисования правильного треугольника, в ней я не только рисую линии, но, ещё и учитываю заливку, единственный, на мой взгляд, недостаток - процедура не нарисует треугольник, когда линия пустая (Pen.Style=psClear). По такому же принципу я однажды написал градиентную заливку треугольника от центра к сторонам.

```
Const
  Grad=Pi/180;

Procedure RightTrigon(Canvas: TCanvas; Const X, Y, R: Integer);
Var
  P: Array[0..3] Of TPoint;
  pc, npc, BGColor: TColor;
  ps: TPenStyle;
  Alpha, pw: LongWord;
  i,j: Byte;
begin
  Alpha:=30;
  If (Canvas.Brush.Style<>bsClear) Then
    Begin
      pc:=Canvas.Pen.Color;
      ps:=Canvas.Pen.Style;
      pw:=Canvas.Pen.Width;
      Randomize;
      Repeat
        BGColor:=RGB(Random(256), Random(256), Random(256));
        npc:=RGB(Random(256), Random(256), Random(256));
      Until ((BGColor<>npc) And (npc<>pc));
      Canvas.Pen.Style:=psClear;
      Canvas.Pen.Color:=BGColor;
      For j:=0 To R-1 Do
        Begin
          For i:=0 To 3 Do
            Begin
              P[i].X:=X+Round((j+1) * Cos(Alpha * Grad));
              P[i].Y:=Y+Round((j+1) * Sin(Alpha * Grad));
              Alpha:=Alpha+120;
            End;
          If (j<R-1) Then Canvas.Pen.Width:=2
          Else Canvas.Pen.Width:=1;
          Canvas.Polyline(P);
        End;
      With Canvas Do
        Begin
          Pen.Style:=psSolid;
          Pen.Width:=1;
          Pen.Color:=npc;
          Polyline(P);
          FloodFill(X, Y, npc, fsBorder);
          Brush.Style:=bsSolid;
          Pen.Width:=pw;
          Pen.Style:=ps;
          Pen.Color:=pc;
          If (ps=psClear) Then
            Begin
              Pen.Style:=psSolid;
              Pen.Color:=Brush.Color;
            End;
          Polyline(P);
        End;
    End
  Else
    Begin
      For i:=0 To 3 Do
        Begin
          P[i].X:=X+Round(R * Cos(Alpha * Grad));
          P[i].Y:=Y+Round(R * Sin(Alpha * Grad));
          Alpha:=Alpha+120;
        End;
      Canvas.Polyline(P);
    End;
End;
```

Comment: Если озадачиваться заливкой, то лучше (с точки зрения производительности) сразу реализовать работу с Bitmap-ом на уровне указателей. Это, в принципе, не очень сложно. Заодно сделать интерполяцию цвета между вершинами. Потом допилить матрицу преобразований, Z-buffer - и вот минимальный 3д движок , хехе )

offtopic: для вставки кода лучше использовать не PRE, а кнопку 101010.

Comment: Я этот код писал, примерно, год назад для курсовика, поэтому особо сильно не заморачивался: делал по принципу написал - работает.

Comment: Может быть я что то не так сделал, но он почему то не рисует треугольник......

Comment: В процедуру нужно передать 4 параметра: канва, координата X, координата Y и радиус (R) описанной около треугольника окружности. Я эту процедуру много раз тестировал, и она работала... Может быть маленький параметр R указали? Его желательно указывать не меньше, чем 10.

Answer (score 0):

Delphi XE2:

```
  Form1.Canvas.Polygon([TPoint.Create(10, 10), TPoint.Create(15, 15), TPoint.Create(10, 23)]);
```